# How to create a display table using loops in WebWork? (PG)

Tags: loops, perl

I picked up Perl about a week ago and am now creating problems in WebWorK to help students practice their derivative skills. I would like to print out a table of questions and corresponding answer boxes in the least labor intensive way possible, since these questions will be mass produced.

Up to this point, I have been manually inputting the required code, and a lot of copy-pasting has been required. An example of the current structure is as follows:

```
@questions=(
"x(x+1)",
"x^2(1-x)",
"(x+2)(3x-4)",
"(x-\sqrt{x})(x+\sqrt{x})",
"(x^3-\frac{x^2}{3}-1)(2-x)",
"(x^3-2x)(x^{-2}+\frac{1}{x^4})",
"\frac{x-\sqrt{2x}}{x^2}"
);

BEGIN_TEXT
$BR $BR
Find the derivatives. 
$PAR
END_TEXT

@header=(" f(x) "," f '(x) ");
@header = map {EV3($_) } @header;

TEXT(
begintable(1+scalar(@header)), 
    row(@header),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[0]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[1]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[2]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[3]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[4]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[5]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[6]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
endtable() 
);
```

I would like to use a loop to make things a little cleaner and remove the need to update the rows when the number of questions in a set changes. This is what I have tried so far, but WebWorK does not want to accept it without throwing a syntax error, leading me to believe that I cannot execute a loop within a table construct.

```
@questions=(
"x(x+1)",
"x^2(1-x)",
"(x+2)(3x-4)",
"(x-\sqrt{x})(x+\sqrt{x})",
"(x^3-\frac{x^2}{3}-1)(2-x)",
"(x^3-2x)(x^{-2}+\frac{1}{x^4})",
"\frac{x-\sqrt{2x}}{x^2}"
);

BEGIN_TEXT
$BR $BR
Find the derivatives. 
$PAR
END_TEXT

@header=(" f(x) "," f '(x) ");
@header = map {EV3($_) } @header;

TEXT(
begintable(1+scalar(@header)), 
    row(@header),
    for($i = 0; $i <= $#questions; $i++) {
    row("\[\qquad{$questions[$i]}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10)),
    }
endtable() 
);
```

Being so new to this language, I am having a really hard time applying anything I find online to my specific problem, could someone lend me a hand in figuring out how to accomplish this?

---

Edit:
I inserted the code segment provided by clamp and got the following results:

Code:

```
TEXT(                                                          #71
begintable(1+scalar(@header)),                                 #72
    row(@header),                                              #73
    map {row("\[\qquad{$_}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10))} @questions; #74
endtable()                                                     #75
);                                                             #76
```

Error message:

```
ERRORS from evaluating PG file: 
 syntax error at (eval 28451) line 74, at EOF
syntax error at (eval 28451) line 76, near ") 
)"
```

Comment: After looking around on WebWorK a bit, it seems that it uses a Perl based language called PG.
Perhaps the following can provide some insight: https://webwork.maa.org/wiki/Basic_Perl_syntax

Comment: The for loop does not evaluate to a list. Try to replace it with: `map {row("\[\qquad{$_}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10))} @questions;`

Comment: @clamp I tried inserting the code snippet you provided, and while it makes sense to me that it should work, it throws errors on execution. I will edit the original question and append the results.

Comment: I posted an answer (tested on https://wdemo.webork.rochester.edu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TEXT()` function expects a list of values. Your for loop appears in this parameter list, where it is not useful, because it does not evaluate to a list of values.
Create the values before you call the `TEXT()` function:

```
@questions=(
"x(x+1)",
"x^2(1-x)",
"(x+2)(3x-4)",
"(x-\sqrt{x})(x+\sqrt{x})",
"(x^3-\frac{x^2}{3}-1)(2-x)",
"(x^3-2x)(x^{-2}+\frac{1}{x^4})",
"\frac{x-\sqrt{2x}}{x^2}");

@formatted = map { row("\[\qquad{$_}\qquad\]",ans_rule(10))} @questions;

BEGIN_TEXT
$BR $BR
Find the derivatives. 
$PAR
END_TEXT

@header=(" f(x) "," f '(x) ");
@header = map {EV3($_) } @header;

TEXT(
begintable(1+scalar(@header)), 
    row(@header),
    @formatted,
endtable() 
);
```